# How to access cells in excel from dll

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have created a C++ based dll and imported it into Excel VBA code.

I am able to send data between the dll and VBA code.

My question is, how can i read or write data directly into a cell in excel sheet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a Range from VBA to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42118272/11683)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate to me (or i might have not understood). I need to write some data bytes from the dll directly to the cells in the caller excel vba sheet.

Comment: How are you going to achieve that if not by passing a `Range` instance to the dll? If you meant to call the dll function from a cell, then just do that.

Comment: Hello GSerg, Got It! Can you please add your comment as answer so that i can mark it (as answer) and close this thread?

Comment: I'm not sure which part is the answer.

Comment: "call the dll function from a cell" and information in the link "Pass a Range..."

Comment: Those are mutually exclusive. What are you doing, passing the range or calling from a cell? If you are doing both you are most likely doing something wrong.

Comment: No No, i am not doing both. I am calling the functions from cells. The cells show the return values from the functions.